# Enforcing garbage collection of module level variables?

Tags: python, memory-management

Say I load a big data file used within a module but only care about something derived from it that requires very little memory. What is the best way to structure a module so that it doesn't keep unwanted data in memory when I load it as a module.

Something like:

```
# getstuff.py
from importlib_resources import files

data = files('path.to.file').joinpath('big.one').read_text()
stuff_i_care_about = some_complicated_operation(data)

# __init__.py
from .getstuff import stuff_i_care_about
```

What is the best way to make sure that `data` is freed? `del` + `gc.collect()`? Wrap it in a function? Might it be freed automatically in some versions anyway?

Comment: Did you mean `data = None`?

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, that would work!

Comment: CPython uses reference counting. So as long as `data` is the only variable containing the data, it will be deleted as soon as you either delete or reassign the variable. You don't need to force GC.